# Missing IPsec package in Solaris 10

Tags: software-installation, solaris, ipsec

I'm running Solaris 10 v5/08. Running `svcs -a | grep ipsec` returns nothing, so I have reason to believe IPsec isn't installed (or isn't showing up for some other reason). How can I make sure it is installed and set up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4554/ipsec-ov-21/index.html) states "Starting in the Solaris 10 4/09 release, IPsec is managed by SMF." As you are using an older release, it is expected for ipsec not to show up as a service.